# App virtual credit exchange for real-world gift allowed on AppStore?

Tags: iphone, app-store

Does AppStore allow rewarding top players with real world gifts?

For example, in an iPhone game, the top 5 high-score players receive a T-shirt/book/watch?

Are there any apps doing something similar already? Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because really, nothing to do with programming. AND such discussion only stays fresh for a few months. Better on gamedev if anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to answer such questions **as the situation changes drastically over the years**. Purely for example, some text from Apple **only relevant at time of writing**:

> "20. Contests, sweepstakes, lotteries,
> and raffles
>
> 20.1 Sweepstakes and contests must be sponsored by the developer/company of
> the app
>
> 20.2 Official rules for sweepstakes and contests, must be presented in the
> app and make it clear that Apple is
> not a sponsor or involved in the
> activity in any manner
>
> 20.3 It must be permissible by law for the developer to run a lottery app,
> and a lottery app must have all of the
> following characteristics:
> consideration, chance, and a prize
>
> 20.4 Apps that allow a user to directly purchase a lottery or raffle
> ticket in the app will be rejected "

Note however that Apple is making it **your problem** with the law: **you face the same problems of ANY type of company, doing ANY type of promotion.**

There are incredibly many regulations involved with companies giving away stuff in promotions (in every jurisdiction).